# Join two tables and order by single column

Tags: mysql, join

Lets say I have two tables, one of customers and one of orders. The goal is to show a timeline of when customers joined along when orders where created.

**Customer**

```
id name created
1  John 1
2  Mary 3
3  Bob  5
```

**Order**

```
id   created
aaa  2
bbb  4
ccc  6
```

**Combined**

```
id  name  created
1   John  1
aaa       2
2   Mary  3
bbb       4
3   Bob   5
ccc       6
```

Originally I started with a join table that held the ids of each table and the date they were created. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of joining these two tables and ordering by the date created.

Alternatively, I could look up the last X records and manually merging the results in the code. Looking for advice here.

Comment: You need a foreign key, such as `customer_id`, on the order table that can point back an order to a specific customer.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'm not trying to combine the two rows into one. I'll update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this query should give you the results you want. It produces a list of Customers and Orders, sorted by `created`. Rows are identified by a 'Customer' or 'Order' value:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'Customer' AS type, id, name, created FROM Customer
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Order', id, '', created FROM Orders) u
ORDER BY created, type
```

Output:

```
type        id      name    created
Customer    1       John    111
Order       aaa             111
Customer    2       Mary    222
Order       bbb             222
Customer    3       Bob     333
Order       ccc             333
```

Comment: Looks like you understood it correctly. Let me confirm the solution.

Comment: @Rawr have just edited to include customer name as well

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.